# How to indicate that content in an iframe is untrusted

Tags: javascript, phishing, sandbox

As part of a website I am developing, untrusted content is displayed in a sandboxed iframe. The content is loaded using the `srcdoc` attribute, but the iframe is sandboxed using `sandbox="allow-scripts"`, so the untrusted content does not have same-origin access. However, I am concerned about malicious scripts running within the iframe. Particularly, I am concerned about phishing, since the domain displayed in the addressbar will be my website, and things like malicious alert() messages. What is a good way to either avoid this issue in the first place, or make it clear to visitors that the content is untrusted? (I can't turn off the allow-scripts permission because there are legitimate scripts that need to run in the content).

Comment: `alert(1)` popups will appear outside the iframe, so no amount of warning or indication will help with that point. Are you looking for a UI solution or a programatic one?

Comment: @schroeder I was thinking more of a UI solution, but a programmatic one would be great too.

Comment: banner ads on sites sometimes have a special border and a UI element saying something like "Sponsored Content" - would that kind of thing suffice for UI?

Comment: If you're to allow only limited number of sites to be iframed, you may whitelist the domains and disallow others.

You can put a notice that the content inside the frame is from another origin, and that you're not entirely sure that the content is from trusted source, as said, put a border for the framed content.